# Google chart bug when using PDO connection

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to use google charts to show my database values. I'm using PDO for my database queries inside a class where I instantiate it as an object on my HTML page inside my PHP tag. However the google chart is not working the way it should be, the piechart title and the names of the values are not showing up.

This is my current output
[image: my current output]

This is what I want to be shown
[image: my desired output]

my html page:

```
<?php
 $dashboard = new userview; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['ticketstatus', 'statusnumber'],
        <?php

             $dashboard->getstatuscount(); 
        ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Request Status'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

</script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"> 
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

my query class :

```
class userview extends dbh{
public function getstatuscount() {
        $sql = "SELECT ticketstatus, COUNT(*) as statusnumber FROM ticketpractice GROUP BY ticketstatus";
        $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
         echo "['".$row['ticketstatus']."',".$row['statusnumber']."],"  ;
        }
    }
   }
```

my database class

```
 class dbh
 {

private  $dbhost = "localhost";
private $dbusername = "root";
private $dbpassword = "";
private $dbname = "myphplessons";

protected function connect () {

$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->dbhost . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
$pdo = new PDO ($dsn,$this->dbusername, $this->dbpassword);
$pdo->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $pdo;
}
```

}

Comment: So start by checking what JS code your PHP actually created in that place …

Comment: is the above html / javascript the full version?

Comment: @WhiteHat actually there is a link tag for my css inside also the header, by the way I have working around on it and found out that link tag is causing the bug.

Comment: this is the link tag '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cssticket.css">'

Comment: `$dashboard->getstatuscount()();`  `getstatuscount` doesn't return a function so why `()()`? Surely this would be triggering a syntax error

Comment: Also, it's inadvisable to _roll-your-own_ JSON. Better to create a data structure (array) and use `json_encode()`

Comment: I have correct the object it goes like this now `$dashboard->getstatuscount();` but I'm still getting the error, yeah Phil thanks for your answers however I'm not familiar yet with JSON

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the current state of your code. Also, check the rendered HTML source in your browser (ie _"View page source"_) and see exactly what JS you're creating. Check for errors in your browser console too

Comment: I manage to fix my chart I guess. The chart title and values are now showing. I have just rename my `css` file and remove the global div tag css lines in it. I don't know what the reason why it messes with the google char in the first place.